# How to make the screen stay off until a "real" input

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

When I lock my session with Super + L or with Ctrl + Alt + L, the computer locks itself and after about 5 seconds the screen begins to fade to black, and then turns off (no signal).

Sometimes it randomly turns back on, and then it never turns back off again. I'm pretty sure that I haven't touched anything, unless my mouse can pick up the vibrations of the table when music is playing (it also happens with no music).

I have no idea what could be causing it. I have tried to relate it to Firefox or Clementine running, but I haven't found any relation.

I suppose it's the system trying to display something for a brief time, like an icon wiggle from unity or similar.

My installation is pretty much stock Ubuntu 14.04 (I have just run apt-get install ubuntu-desktop and there was nothing missing).